# Add behavior in imported ant task?

Tags: inheritance, ant

I'm setting up a common ant file (build-common.xml) for my team, which will be imported from each sub-project's build.xml file.  Is there a way to define a "clean" task (for example) in build-common.xml such that individual build.xml files can either leave it unchanged or add behavior to it?  The equivalent in Java would be:

```
@Override
void clean()
{
    super.clean();
    /* do something additional */
}
```

I am using the latest release of ant: 1.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question at http://wiki.apache.org/ant/NewAntFeaturesInDetail/Import:

```
    <project name="main">
      <import file="config/common.xml" />

      <target name="build" depends="common.build">
        ...
      </target>
      ...
   </project>
```